# Logging Kafka Partition and offset from Apache Storm Trident

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, offset, lag, trident

Where are Kafka Partitions and corresponding Offsets stored while consuming messages from Kafka using Apache Storm Trident ? I could find something in Storm Zookeeper under `ls /transactional/<StreamName>/coordinator/meta`. But I am unable to understand what are these offsets and to which partition that they belong to ? How can I check Consumer Lag while running Trident Topology ?

Comment: Please post which Storm version you're using, and whether you're using storm-kafka or storm-kafka-client.

Comment: I am using Storm 1.2.1 and storm-kafka-cliet of the same version.